# What is the difference between habitable and Goldilocks zone?

Tags: astrophysics, terminology, planets, solar-system, exoplanets

If I am right, [Habitable Zone](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitable_zone) means that a planet is on such a distance from its Star which makes it good candidate for supporting some sort of life.

But then what is [Goldilocks zone](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=Goldilocks+zone) and how is it different from Habitable Zone?

Comment: They refer to the same thing.

Comment: @DmitryBrant that should be an answer

Comment: Don't understand why my question has been voted down. Asking a layman question and being voted down. If this is the trend on Stackoverflow continuously then it will lose its significance ahead.

Comment: @FaisalMushtaq This site isn't intended for laymen. Besides, as Dmitry's answer shows, the answer can be had with the slightest research effort on existing resources.

Answer (score 1):

They both refer to the [same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstellar_habitable_zone).

> The habitable zone is also called the Goldilocks zone, a metaphor of
>   the children's fairy tale of Goldilocks and the Three Bears, in which
>   a little girl chooses from sets of three items, ignoring the ones that
>   are too extreme (large or small, hot or cold, etc.), and settling on
>   the one in the middle, which is "just right".